# ¿Hay forma de "abrir" los objetos almacenados dentro de un bucket en GCS?

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage

Estoy intentando utilizar la libreria excelize de golang para poder abrir archivos excel y manipular o, al menos, poder extraer las tablas de ahi pero no logro poder acceder a los objetos dentro del bucket.

```
file, err := excelize.OpenFile("Book1.xlsx")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
```

Aqui deberia pasarle tan solo el nombre pero aun utilizando el nombre incluido en el payload del evento (triggereado al almacenar un archivo dentro de cierto bucket) no funciona, tampoco pasando la URI directa o con un object.Handler de la siguiente forma:

```
client, err := storage.NewClient(ctx)

if err != nil {
    //Handling err
}

object := client.Bucket(e.Bucket).Object(e.Name)

//Aqui e.SelfLink representa el atributo "selflink" dado por el payload del evento
f, err := excelize.OpenFile(e.SelfLink)
```

La pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna forma de poder acceder a estos archivos almacenados y manipularlos como si trabajara un archivo en local? Mi meta es poder, si no puedo manipularlos, al menos leer las tablas dentro del documento excel y poder convertirlas en XML para manejar esa informacion en otro microservicio. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré un metodo llamado excelize.OpenReader(r io.Reader) al cual, al pasarle un reader del objeto almacenado en cloud storage te permite leer el archivo almacenado de forma de poder leerlo y sobreescribirlo de la siguiente forma:

```
objectReader, err := client.Bucket(event.Bucket).Object(event.Name).NewReader(ctx)

if err != nil {

    log.Printf("Err new reader: %v", err)
    return err
}

defer objectReader.Close()

f, err := excelize.OpenReader(objectReader)

if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)

    return err
}
```